# Android app doesn't build because of issues when checking AAR metadata

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, aar

I upgrade my old android application maded in an older Android Studio. The new Android studio suggest me to upgrade a lot of libary versions. But at the end, it doesn't compile my project.
This is my build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codename1.myapp1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 22
        versionName "2.2.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} 

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
}
```

The error is this:
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8f8dfbea7461eb4b096b7a7771e0ff80\transformed\appcompat-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ce5785984a5439e358ec1b014f6d367a\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\caef44bc0f4fe78c06c6508978f60bc1\transformed\jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\92708834b1c092ddf07d1634926df188\transformed\jetified-emoji2-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\919b1e91a07ddbf34272a620f8cba519\transformed\core-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d9db6b6f9ce68129424c2ebe8909f584\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\sethi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\266539821f1efc21fd3ddc0953503221\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```